# Does the sequence $\frac{n!}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot ... \cdot (2n-1)}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to determine if this sequence converges as part of answering whether it's monotonic:

$$
\left\{\frac{n!}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot ... \cdot (2n-1)}\right\}
$$

First, I tried expanding it a bit to see if I could remove common factors in the numerator and denominator:

$$
\left\{\frac{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot ...\cdot n}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 9 \cdot ...\cdot (2n-1)}\right\}
$$

Second, I tried looking at elements of the sequence with common factors removed:

$$
1, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{2\cdot 4}{5\cdot 7}, \frac{2\cdot 4}{7\cdot 9}, ...
$$

Third, I tried looking at the elements again as fractions without simplifications:

$$
\frac{1}{1}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{6}{15}, \frac{24}{105}, \frac{120}{945}, ...
$$

Last, I tried searching for similar questions on [Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com) and I found one for [$\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2n)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519540/does-the-sequence-a-n-frac1-cdot-3-cdot-5-cdots-2n-12-cdot-4-cdot) but I didn't understand how that might apply to my question. So, any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Let $a_n=\dfrac{n!}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-1)}$. What you already did basically shows that that $a_{n+1}=a_n\cdot\dfrac{n+1}{2n+1}$, so $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\dfrac{n+1}{2n+1}$. So the ratio of one term to the previous term approaches $\frac{1}{2}$ in the limit. Does that help?

Comment: @SteveKass, I did notice that but I forgot to mention it. I didn't quite understand what it meant because the actual limit to infinity is clearly less than $\frac{1}{2}$ since the third element is $\frac{6}{15} < \frac{1}{2}$ and the sequence seems to be strictly decreasing.

Comment: The ratio is what approaches $\frac12$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reciprocal of the term of interest is

$$\begin{align}
\frac{(2n-1)!!}{n!}&=\left(\frac{(2n-1)}{n}\right)\left(\frac{(2(n-1)-1)}{(n-1)}\right)\left(\frac{(2(n-2)-1)}{(n-2)}\right) \cdots \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\\\\
&=\left(2-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(2-\frac{1}{n-1}\right)\left(2-\frac{1}{n-2}\right) \cdots \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\\\\
&\ge \left(\frac32\right)^{n-1}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we see immediately that the limit of interest is $0$.

Comment: I was hesitant to ask because your answer seems so out of my league but, since you offer, I did have a couple questions: 1. Why use the reciprocal? 2. Why the double factorial?

Comment: The term of interest has that double factorial term in the denominator.  The reason for my analyzing the reciprocal is that the division of each term is easy to express.  -Mark

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry it took me such a long time to follow-up.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure. -Mark

Answer (score 5):

$$|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=|\frac{n+1}{2n+1}| \to\frac{1}{2}<1$$

So by the ratio test $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges and we must have $a_n \to 0$ by the divergence test.

In fact for $n \geq 1$, $\frac{n+1}{2n+1}$ is decreasing so,

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}:=f(n) \leq \frac{1+1}{2(1)+1}=\frac{2}{3}$$

And because the positive reals are closed under multiplication it follows that,

$$0<a_{n+1} \leq \frac{2}{3}a_n$$

The solution to $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=f(n)$ is for $n >1$, $a_n=a_1 \prod_{x=1}^{n-1} f(x)$, but because $f(n)=:\frac{n+1}{2n+1} \leq \frac{2}{3}$ then for $n>1$:

$$0<a_n \leq a_1 \prod_{x=1}^{n-1} \frac{2}{3}=a_1 \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}$$

Because $x \geq a$ and $y \geq b$ $\implies$ $xy \geq ab$. And it's easy to show that the above inequality holds for $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$a_{n+1} = a_n \frac{n+1}{2n+1}$  Each number in the sequence is slightly more that (1/2) as the one before it.

for $n>3, \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 0.6$

$a_n < 0.4 (0.6)^{n-2}$

The sequence converges to 0.

Comment: Why do you say each number in the sequence is slightly more than $\frac{1}{2}$ since it seems the third element is $\frac{6}{15} < \frac{1}{2}$ and the subsequent elements keep decreasing. Did I not calculate correctly?

Comment: @PrettyAntlers He's not saying that the _members_ of the sequence are slightly more than $\frac12$; he's saying that the _ratio_ between successive members is.

Comment: 1/2 its preceding element!

Answer (score 1):

Using Henry W.'s answer $$A_n=\frac{n!}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot ... \cdot (2n-1)} = 2^n\frac{(n!)^2 }{(2n)!}$$ $$\log(A_n)= 2\log(n!) + n \log( 2) - \log \big((2n)!\big)$$ Now, using [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation)
$$\log(p!)\approx p\log(p)-p+\frac 12\log(2\pi p)$$ $$\log(A_n)\approx \frac{1}{2} \log (\pi  n)-n \log (2)$$ $n$ varies faster than $\log(n)$; so $\log(A_n)\to -\infty$ and $A_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [odd-factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69162/proving-formula-for-product-of-first-n-odd-numbers)

$$\frac{n!}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot ... \cdot (2n-1)} = \frac{(n!)^2 2^n}{(2n)!}
$$
Taking logarithm,
$$ \log\frac{(n!)^2 2^n}{(2n)!} = 2\log n! + n \log 2 - \log (2n!)
$$
so...

Comment: I'm not very comfortable with factorials, so how would you simplify them either as a fraction ($\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$) or as logarithms ($2\log n! - \log(2n!)$)? I removed the parts that I thought would not be related but I might've unknowingly oversimplified.

Comment: @PrettyAntlers You can use Stirling's approximation.

Comment: @PrettyAntlers Expand the logarithm ($\log n! = \log 1 + \log 2 + \cdots + \log n$) and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

As far as monotonicity is concerned, write the sequence recursively:

\begin{align}
a_1 =&\  1 \\
a_{n} =&\ a_1\frac{n}{2n + 1} 
\end{align}

Then look at the difference between $a_{n + 1}$ and $a_{n}$:

\begin{align}
a_{n + 1} - a_{n} =&\ a_n\frac{n+1}{2(n + 1) + 1} - a_n\\
=&\ a_n\left(\frac{n+1}{2(n + 1) + 1} - 1\right) \\
=&\ a_n\left(\frac{n+1}{2n + 3} - 1\right) \\
=&\ a_n\frac{n + 1 - 2n - 3}{2n + 3} \\
=&\ a_n\frac{-n - 2}{2n + 3}\\
=&\ -a_n\frac{n + 2}{2n + 3}
\end{align}

Clearly this sequence monotonically decreases since the difference between each consecutive element is negative.

As far as convergence goes, one can certainly see that, in the limit that $n \rightarrow \infty$ that this difference will tend towards $\Delta a = -a_n\frac{1}{2}$.  The negative is showing that the next term is one half smaller than the previous.  For the sequence to converge, $\Delta a$ must tend towards $0$--the only possible way for this to happen is if $a_n$ eventually tends towards $0$.  Thus *if the sequence converges*, it converges to $0$.  And I put that in italics because *I have not shown* that the sequence converges--it seems to me that this is possible through the fact that it's positive definite and monotonically decreases (since it cannot monotonically decrease without crossing zero and *not* converge--but that's more of an intuitive argument).

Comment: Because it's monotonically decreasing (I proved this) _and_ it's positive definite, it _must_ be bounded.

Comment: Got it, I deleted my comment after I noticed the additional paragraph in your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear a "sequence" or function can monotonically decrease without converging to $0$, such as $f(x) = 1 + e^{-x}$.

Answer (score -1):

Just manipulate the Wallis product for $\pi$.

Comment: It would greatly improve this comment-like response if you walk through the manipulation required (and its justification).