# Show that ${\frac{n!}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot...\cdot(2n-1)}}$ is monotonic and bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Once I show that the sequence is monotonic decreasing using the definition $a_n\geq a_{n+1}$, is it sufficient to say "Since it is a nonnegative decreasing sequence, then its greatest lower bound is zero", or do I have to show $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n!}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot...\cdot(2n-1)}}=0$ using a comparison sequence (in which I am unsure what to compare and squeeze it with). Note: I cannot use the Epsilon-N definition per my professor's instructions.

Comment: If the sequence is $a_n$, then $a_{n+1}/a_n = (n+1)/(2n+1) < 1$.

Comment: I upvoted PrincessEev's answer because it answers exactly to the question you formulated. If your intended question was more demanding, may be you should edit your post to make it explicit.

Comment: It is not even clear whether your problem is to show that the sequence is monotonic and bounded (title) or that it converges to $0$ (body).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the sequence $\frac{n!}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot ... \cdot (2n-1)}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722673/does-the-sequence-fracn1-cdot-3-cdot-5-cdot-cdot-2n-1-converge) especially [that answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1722688)

Comment: Hello, thank you for the link. I do not understand how showing $a_n<(0.4)(0.6)^{n-2}$ implies that the sequence converges to zero. Is it an application of the squeeze theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it sufficient to say "Since it is a nonnegative decreasing sequence, then its greatest lower bound is zero"

Well, no -- mainly for the reason that you don't know that its greatest lower bound would be zero. (Consider, for instance, $a_n = 1 + \frac 1 n$.)

But yes, a non-negative decreasing sequence must be bounded. In particular, $|a_n| \le a_1$ (or whatever the first index of concern is) for any such sequence.

One should also note that, yes, monotone bounded sequences are necessarily convergent. Of course, this does not make a claim as to what the limit is, so if your goal is to show that your sequence approaches $0$, more work needs to be done.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. If my understanding is correct, since $0 < a_n < a_1$, and it is a monotonic decreasing sequence, then an infimum must exist?

Comment: Yes, and in particular you should be able to show that the infimum in question is the limit of the sequence as well.

Comment: That clarifies my question. Thank you again!