# Examining convergence of the series.

Tags: convergence-divergence

Examine convergence of the series $$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot4}-\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{2\cdot4\cdot6}+\cdots$$

Comment: Use Stirling's approximation.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I think things are much easier here ;)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have

$$a_n=(-1)^n\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k-1) } {\prod_{k=1}^n (2k) }=\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}$$ and then
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n} x^n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's denote $a_n=\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n)}$ and consider:
$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=1+\frac{1}{2n+1}$$
So by Gauss test we have absolute divergence and conditional convergence by Leibniz test and [for limit 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899857/mathematical-problem-induction-frac12-cdot-frac34-cdots-frac2n-12n-frac)

Comment: For the Leibniz test we need to show $a_n\to0$.  I don't see how this follows from the above.

Comment: @saulspatz. Added to answer (it automatically appeared to me on the right column).