# $\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{8}{9} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{995}{996} \cdot \frac{998}{999}$ and $0.1$ which is bigger?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence, induction

$\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{8}{9} \cdot ... \cdot  \frac{995}{996}  \cdot  \frac{998}{999}$ and $0.1$ which is bigger?

The expression seems a bit different from [Mathematical induction problem: $\frac12\cdot \frac34\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n}<\frac1{\sqrt{2n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899857/mathematical-induction-problem-frac12-cdot-frac34-cdots-frac2n-12n-frac?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: The former is 0.49.... so it's quite clear.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I think there's an implied $\dots$.

Comment: Did you forget the "$\cdots$" in the expression ?

Comment: Also, it should be 995 instead of 955.

Comment: Do you mean $\prod_{n=1}^{333} \frac{3n-1}{3n}$ on the left?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. sorry I fixed them

Comment: bc tells me it's slightly larger than 0.1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider three products:

$$
P_1 = {1\over2}\cdot{4\over5}\cdot...\cdot{997\over998}\\
P_2 = {2\over3}\cdot{5\over6}\cdot...\cdot{998\over999}\\
P_3 = {3\over4}\cdot{6\over7}\cdot...\cdot{999\over1000}\\
$$
Obviously, $P_1<P_2<P_3$, because they all have equally many terms and the corresponding terms are all ordered the same way. Also, because of telescoping, $P_1P_2P_3={1\over1000}$, which means that $P_1<0.1$ and $P_3>0.1$. Pity it doesn't tell us much about $P_2$, which is what we need.

We'll have to make a better estimate. What about the *geometric mean* of the corresponding terms of $P_1$ and $P_3$? That would be
$$\sqrt{{3n-2\over3n-1}\cdot{3n\over3n+1}} = \sqrt{(3n-1)^2-1\over(3n)^2-1} = \sqrt{{(3n-1)^2\over(3n)^2}\cdot{1-{1\over(3n-1)^2}\over1-{1\over(3n)^2}}}<{3n-1\over3n}$$

That's it; $P_2>\sqrt{P_1P_3}$, hence $P_2>\sqrt[3]{P_1P_2P_3}=0.1$

Comment: Very nice (+1)    $\; \; $